# Multiple Dropdownlists bound to one Dropdownlist

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, sqldatasource

I'm really not sure how to ask this in a good or correct way. I need sort of help here. I'm not sure if this question was already answered in a different way. So please be patient.

How do I make 3 dropdownlists to be connected together? For example making dropdownlist2 and 3 as Enabled="false" so the user cannot touch them but dropdownlist1 as Enabled="true" making that one the only one they need to select.

dropdownlist1 to 3 are using data from the same table in SQL Server basically DDL1 has data called Unit, DDL2 has data called Department and DDL3 has data called Direction. All three of them use the same id. So the user only need to select the Unit and then the others Department and Direction autoselect their choice based of the id selected in Unit.

That's the idea I want to do but I cannot find a way to do it. I don't want to combine all data into just one slot what I want is the information to be shown separated so the user can see if the system selected the right department and direction from the unit he/she chose.

That's the code I have. Is just the html. I have no idea how to start what I need...I'm not sure if this is how you do this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label Text="Unit:" runat="server" />
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="descriptionUnit" DataValueField="idTest"></asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource2" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:descriptionTest %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [idTest], [descriptionUnit] FROM [Test]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
  </div>                                
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <asp:Label Text="Deparment" runat="server" />
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="descriptionDeparment" DataValueField="idTest"></asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource3" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:descriptionTest %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [idTest], [descriptionDeparment] FROM [Test]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <asp:Label Text="Direction" runat="server" />
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="descriptionDirection" DataValueField="idTest"></asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"  ID="SqlDataSource4" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:descriptionTest %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [idTest], [descriptionDirection] FROM [Test]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
  </div>                               
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "dropdownlist1 to 3 are using data from the same table..." "All three of them use the same id." What you are saying means all the data you need is in the same row, so you don't need cascading dropdowns. Just want to make sure you're aware of that.

Comment: For cascading dropdowns, you need a `WHERE` clause in your 2nd and 3rd dropdowns' `SELECT` statements, `... WHERE [idTest] = ?`. As soon as you add a WHERE clause, the dropdowns will automatically give you an option to select where the value comes from, and you can select the first dropdown.

Comment: Oh thanks wazz! I ended using textboxes instead so 2 textboxes would show the data of department and direction so unit is the only selected one and since unit holds the id which is the one the table will record thanks to foreign key so I did that. I thought it was easier and works in the end. But thank you Wazz!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I suggest that you remove the 3 data sources. Just delete them, and for the 3 combo boxes remove the datasource setting (this one).

DataSSourceID   (go into all 3 drop downs and BLANK out that setting).

Ok, so now in the forms load event, we fill out ONLY the first comb box.

eg this:

```
If IsPostBack = false then
   ' first time page load - fill the 1st combo box
   DropDownList2.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT idTest, descriptionDeparment FROM Test")
End If
```

Set Dropdown 2 and 3 to have auto post back = true.

At this point 1st dropdown will be filled.

The user selects a value. In the Selected index changed event (1st combo), then you have this code:

```
        Dim strSQL As String
        strSQL = " SELECT idTest, descriptionDeparment FROM Test " & _
                 " WHERE DDL2 = '" & DropDownList.DataTextField & "'"
        DropDownList3.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        DropDownList3.DataBind()
```

And do the above same for DropDownList2 index changed event.

I don't have the field names correct, but simply set the sql of the 2nd drop list based on whatever value the first dropdownlist was set to.

And to save typing, then I have a handy routine called MyRst, and I use it for filling grids, listviews, or in this case a drop down list.

All that routine does is return a table object based on given sql, and that routine looks like this:

```
Public Function Myrst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL,
                            New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test4))
        Try
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        Catch ex As Exception
            rstData = Nothing
        End Try

    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

In above, of course replace my use of settings to your given connection string. This routine also means thus you over ever have ONE connection string location in your whole application.

And it also de-clutters the web form - no need to drop in a data  source control for the sql to feed the dropdown list (and thus VERY easy to make/have the sql be dynamic based on previous drop down selections.

So, just repeat that 2nd bit of code for the 2nd dropdown list to filter/restrict the 3rd combo box.

Don't forget for dropdown 1 and 2 to set auto postback = true. The 3rd dropdown of course does not have any code.

Also not knowing your column names used?

```
DropDownList.SelectedValue   - this gets you first PK row
DropDownList.DataTextField   - this gets you the 2nd column
DropDownList.Text            - this ALSO gets you the 2nd column
```

So, it is assumed that you setup the dropdown list with:

```
DataValueField   = "ID"
DataTextField    = 2nd description column
```

So, check the data value field, and data text field in the dropdown list. You VERY likey used a wizard to fill them out - and they set the above 2 column settings.

So, auto postback = true for the first two, and of course choose/change the above sql to restrict based on whatever column you want. If the column in question is NOT actually in the first combo box, then pick up the row based on PK id, and grab the other column that way to filter the 2nd dropdown list. Given we have that handy MyRst() routine, then it rather short work to have an additional query in the the first combo box index changed event that gets/grabs the actual column you need/want to filter on.

Comment: Oh thanks Albert! I ended using textboxes instead so 2 textboxes would show the data of department and direction so unit is the only selected one and since unit holds the id which is the one the table will record thanks to foreign key so I did that. I thought it was easier and works in the end. But thank you Albert!